# How to display video duration on onmouseover over video thumbs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a page with video thumbs. I wonder how i can display video duration onmouseover (**display the duration in a blackbox in lower left corner of image**)the thumb image and hide it again onmouseout? currently as you see in demo the video duration is visiable at all time but i want to make it visiable only when user puts the mouse over the thumb image . I be happy if you guys help me do this task.Thanks in advance.

**demo on fiddle :**http://jsfiddle.net/shodaburp/k6yAQ/1/

```
<div class="ListSlideDown">
    <div class="ListFadeIn">
        <div class="CurrentPage">1</div>
        <div class="IsLastPage">0</div>
        <div class="SortColumn">latest</div>
        <div class="Item ItemLeft">
            <div class="Clipping">
                <a class="ImageLink" href="/videos/vid1" title="video1">
                    <img class="ItemImage" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/0.jpg" alt="video 1" />
                    <img class="OverlayIcon" src="http://shodaburp.com/jsfiddle/playbutton.png" alt="" />
                </a>
                <a class="DurationInfo" onmouseover="showDuration2(this);" onmouseout="hideDuration2(this);" href="/videos/vid1"><span class="Text">51:57</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="Title">
                <a href="/videos/vid1" title="video 1">video 1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="VideoAge">1 day before</div>
            <div class="PlaysInfo">broadcast: 604</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Item ItemMiddle">
            <div class="Clipping">
                <a class="ImageLink" href="/videos/vid2" title="video2">
                    <img class="ItemImage" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/0.jpg" alt="video 2" />
                    <img class="OverlayIcon" src="http://shodaburp.com/jsfiddle/playbutton.png" alt="" />
                </a>
                <a class="DurationInfo" onmouseover="showDuration2(this);" onmouseout="hideDuration2(this);" href="/videos/vid2"><span class="Text">12:23</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="Title">
                <a href="/videos/vid2" title="video 2">video 2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="VideoAge">1 day before</div>
            <div class="PlaysInfo">broadcast: 7531</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Item ItemRight">
            <div class="Clipping">
                <a class="ImageLink" href="/videos/vid3" title="video3‌">
                    <img class="ItemImage" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/0.jpg" alt="video3‌" />
                    <img class="OverlayIcon" src="http://shodaburp.com/jsfiddle/playbutton.png" alt="" />
                </a>
                <a class="DurationInfo" onmouseover="showDuration2(this);" onmouseout="hideDuration2(this);" href="/videos/vid3"><span class="Text">17:36</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="Title">
                <a href="/videos/vid3" title="video 3‌">video 3‌</a>
            </div>
            <div class="VideoAge">1 day before</div>
            <div class="PlaysInfo">broadcast: 996</div>
        </div>
        <div class="LineSpacer3"></div>
        <div class="Item ItemLeft">
            <div class="Clipping">
                <a class="ImageLink" href="/videos/vid4" title="video4">
                    <img class="ItemImage" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/0.jpg" alt="video 4" />
                    <img class="OverlayIcon" src="http://shodaburp.com/jsfiddle/playbutton.png" alt="" />
                </a>
                <a class="DurationInfo" onmouseover="showDuration2(this);" onmouseout="hideDuration2(this);" href="/videos/vid4"><span class="Text">31:57</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="Title">
                <a href="/videos/vid4" title="video 4">video 4</a>
            </div>
            <div class="VideoAge">1 day before</div>
            <div class="PlaysInfo">broadcast: 604</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Item ItemMiddle">
            <div class="Clipping">
                <a class="ImageLink" href="/video/video5" title="video5">
                    <img class="ItemImage" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/0.jpg" alt="video 5" />
                    <img class="OverlayIcon" src="http://shodaburp.com/jsfiddle/playbutton.png" alt="" />
                </a>
                <a class="DurationInfo" onmouseover="showDuration2(this);" onmouseout="hideDuration2(this);" href="/videos/vid5"><span class="Text">2:23</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="Title">
                <a href="/videos/vid2" title="video 5">video 5</a>
            </div>
            <div class="VideoAge">1 day before</div>
            <div class="PlaysInfo">broadcast: 2531</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Item ItemRight">
            <div class="Clipping">
                <a class="ImageLink" href="/videos/vid6" title="video6‌">
                    <img class="ItemImage" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/0.jpg" alt="video6‌" />
                    <img class="OverlayIcon" src="http://shodaburp.com/jsfiddle/playbutton.png" alt="" />
                </a>
                <a class="DurationInfo" onmouseover="showDuration2(this);" onmouseout="hideDuration2(this);" href="/videos/vid6"><span class="Text">12:36</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="Title">
                <a href="/videos/vid6" title="video 6‌">video 6‌</a>
            </div>
            <div class="VideoAge">1 day before</div>
            <div class="PlaysInfo">broadcast: 196</div>
        </div>
        <div class="LineSpacer3"></div>
        <div class="BottomFix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why would you need JavaScript in this case:

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/habb9/

Just use CSS:

```css
.Clipping{                     /*<--Change to .Clipping*/
    position: relative;
}
.DurationInfo{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    display: none;
}
.Item:hover .DurationInfo{
        display: block;
}
```

And you can even add a nice transition:

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/habb9/2/

```css
.DurationInfo{
    opacity: 0;
    right: -5px;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out,     /*Prefix not included*/
                right .2s ease-in-out;
}
.Item:hover .DurationInfo{
        right: -5px;
        opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks derek i tried to use your solution with sample data in my demo (which has 6 divs) it displays the duration in outside the thumb at lower right side of broadcast time ! furthermore, now it shows more then 3 thumb in row but i wanted 3 thumbs in a row!

Comment: @user1788736 - OK, I see the problem now. See my update. Just change `.Item{` to `.Clipping{`. [Demo (example)](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/k6yAQ/3/)

Comment: @user1788736 - Also I see that you are [trying to make something](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1788736/user1788736?tab=questions) like a page that displays video thumbnails? Try to try it yourself first before asking for answers, because sometimes people might downvoted your question for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

just in case you want to do with jquery you can use `hover` and `mouseleave` methods.

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/k6yAQ/4/